# Failing to update foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have the following association:

```
class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :landowner
end
```

and

```
class Landowner < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :tenants
end
```

In my webapp, when I initialise a `Tenant` object, I add a default `Landowner`, which I have already stored with id of 0:

```
# my initilisation
new_tenant = Tenant.create(landowner_id: 0)
```

The problem I'm running into is that I want to update this `Tenant` object's landowner to a new landowner, say with id of 1. I'm trying to do this through the console with:

```
# I only have one tenant, and I made sure the last landowner is a new different landowner
Tenant.first.landowner = Landowner.last
Tenant.first.save!
```

I don't get any errors but the change does not persist. I have also tried:

```
Tenant.first.update({:landowner_id => 1})
```

but this does not work either (no error, but changes do not persist). Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are reinitialising the object again by calling `first()` on `Tenant` for the second time, try this instead

```
tenant = Tenant.first
tenant.landowner = Landowner.last
tenant.save!
```

This will either save or throw a validation error.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This works when I call this in my controller but the change still does not persist in rails console (with no error). In console, I check to see if changes persist with another `Tenant.first.landowner` call. Is this also reinitliasing it?

Comment: The idea is to not reload instance. When you start by "Tenant" class, you explicitly ask for loading something  from the database. Use the same instance of the record as suggested by Rajdeep Singh.